# How to assign barcodes to specific application fields/textbox

Tags: delphi, barcode

I am writing a Delphi application that can read different barcodes, to enter data into different fields on the same form/page.

Because the same "id" can be used for multiple items (e.g. id 123 could be for parts, material, employee, etc), I need to find a way to:

1. Incorporate the appropriate tag/field into the barcode itself, in any format (e.g. userid=123 or partid=123),
2. parse this barcode info into a relevant field/value pair in order to insert the data in the right application textbox/select/radio button/etc.

It's similar to the pairs used in the web URLs where the parser splits pairs into field-value.

Best Regards,

Comment: Codes like UCC / EAN128 simply define a fixed length "application code" which tells the software what kind of data is encoded in the remaining characters. As long as the reader can handle it, this can be used several times within one barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "barcode" is mostly irrelevant. You want to pack a name=value pair into as little space as possible, and later separate the "name" and "value" parts. The "barcode" part is only relevant because it imposes some limitations. *Example*: Depending on the kind of barcode you use, you may only use digits, and not too many of them. So you can't use an "=" sign.

Here's one possible implementation: Assign numbers to all your "names"; Let's say "part number" is 1, "material" is 2, "employee" is 3. Simply prefix the text you put into the barcode with the number!

Encoding is done like this:

```
Barcode.code := '1' + PartNumber;
Barcode.code := '2' + MaterialNumber;
```

Decoding is just as easy:

```
case BarcodeText[1] of
  '1': PartNumber := Copy(BarcodeText,2,MaxInt);
  '2': MaterialNumber := Copy(BarcodeText,2,MaxInt);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be easy. I just have to make sure every barcode is prefixed (or that my barcode can handle some special separator character).